# Application Insight is not showing any data after deployment of ASP.Net Desktop application on server

Tags: .net, azure, azure-application-insights

I am trying to enable Code-based monitoring with application insights to my existing ASP.Net desktop application, I have performed the below steps :

1. Selected Project > Add Application Insights Telemetry > Application Insights Sdk (local) > Next >
   Finish > Close.
   (Installed Application Insights NuGet packages)
2. Opened the ApplicationInsights.config file. and added the InstrumentationKey Before the closing
    in the config file
3. Selected Project > Manage NuGet Packages > Updates. Then updated each
   Microsoft.ApplicationInsights NuGet package to the latest stable release.
4. Also, Installed Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.NLogTarget NuGet package.

When I am running the application locally in debug mode it's sending all the relevant data and exceptions logs to the Application Insight portal.
But when I deploy the same, it does not send any data or exception logs to Application Insight portal.

What could possibly cause this issue and how this can be fixed?

Note: On the same deployment server where above code based implementation is not working, I Installed application insight agent and enabled monitoring using powershell scripts. And that works fine and send data to application insight portal.

Can anyone guide me how can I get the first approach(code-based) working after deployment ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: an *ASP.Net desktop application*? Do you mean a web app (because you mention ASP.Net) or a desktop app with a GUI?

Comment: The project I am working with is indeed ASP.Net web application (.net framework).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you are already updated the related Application Insights packages.
Check the below possibilities to fix no data shared to Application Insights

1. Please make sure in your deployed project contains the below DLL's.

- Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.dll
- Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation.dll
- System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll
- Microsoft.Diagnostics.Instrumentation.Extensions.Intercept.dll

2. Make sure to check **ApplicationInsights.config** file is available in your deployed project. It was Build/Deploy project.
3. In your **firewall**, you might have to open **443 TCP** Port. You can check the data whether we can receive or get by using **Fiddler** and **Perfview**. Refer [IP address used by azure monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ip-addresses)
4. Make sure you have all **Application insights SDK binaries** in your deployed project.
5. In contrast to local debug **web.config**, **web.config** on the server (a.k.a. "Release") is slightly different and does not have AI Module specified.
6. Set **defaultProxy** in **Web.config** if you need to utilise a proxy to transport data **outside your business network**.

#### References

- [asp .net troubleshoot no data share in AI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-troubleshoot-no-data)
- [AI not working when deployed to dev/ On-prem server](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/fb4f53cb-41df-4c44-a9b9-2c521599bc92/app-insights-for-web-application-not-working-when-deployed-to-dev-server)

Comment: Many thanks for your help, Firewall was the issue in my case. Now it's working fine.

Comment: Glad you found the answer helpful. To benefit the community, find the right answers, please do mark the post which was helpful by clicking on [Accept Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) & Up-Vote.