# Getting No data from WCF project to azure application insights

Tags: wcf, azure-application-insights

I am trying to configure application insights for one of my WCF project. I did the configuration using visual studio and redeployed the application in IIS. But it is not sending any request Data to application insights. I have used same configuration method on a sample WCF application and I got request information in my app insights. I have referred some documentation for troubleshooting. It is showing to add appinsights.wcf package from Myget. But I don't have access to that in My workstation. Without Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Wcf package I have successfully connected my demo application to application insights. Please share your suggestion for implementation. My main application is using .net 4.6.1 framework and my sub project has dependencies with another sub projects. Any suggestions is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you read [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-troubleshoot-no-data)?

Answer (score 1):

If your data is not sending into application insights, please go through the [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72372971/15997690).

I hope you are looking for without using **Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Wcf** package in your project.

But without using this package it is **not possible to send Telemetry data into application insights**. Which is the must requirement to use the recent or prerelease **Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Wcf** package in your project.

Refer [here](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-SDK-Labs/blob/master/WCF/readme.md) for more information